# PL/Sql function

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I am tasked to make a PL/SQL function which has two parameters and upon entering them the function has to return a sum of values in the same row of the matching parameters.And if those parameters do not match the data from the database the function must return a ZERO instead of null value.

Here is the code I have:

```
create or replace 
function FGET_EST_INV_SUB (unos_fsub in number, unos_bcycle in number)
return number 
is

amountb number;

cursor C1 is
select SUM (NVL(AMOUNT,0))
from FMDCUSTINVOICEITEMEST
where FSUBSCRIBER_ID= UNOS_FSUB and BCYCLE = UNOS_BCYCLE;

BEGIN

open C1;
FETCH C1 into AMOUNTB;

if C1%NOTFOUND then
   AMOUNTB :=0;
end if;

    close C1; 

return Amountb;

EXCEPTION 
when OTHERS then 
raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

end FGET_EST_INV_SUB;
```

So how can I make it return a zero in the function itself under the condition that either one of the parameters does not match, and please do not say to do it when I am calling the function with the use of NVL. I need it inside of the function.

Comment: it needs to return a zero in the case where FSUBSCRIBER_ID != UNOS_FSUB OR BCYCLE != UNOS_BCYCLE; and I don't know how to incorporate that in the Cursor.

Comment: You set `AMOUNTC` to 0 then return `AMOUNTB`. Why?

Comment: So an `if` would do?

Comment: Yes an If statement would do the trick, but where does it have to go?

Comment: You can default the returned variable to zero in the declaration: `amountb number :=  0;`

Comment: The amountb number :=0; will not give me a ZERO, because if the WHERE statement is not fulfilled the AMOUNT will not be selected meaning the ZERO will not have a place to be placed in.

Comment: Select count(*) as well as selecting sum, and you can detect whether rows were found. SUM(NVL(AMOUNT,0)) is the same as NVL(SUM(AMOUNT),0), but less efficient where multiple rows are involved..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using cursor is a bit of exagerrating things.if you just want to return the sum if parameters are accepted or will return zero if parameters are invalid, you can just place the select statement inside and save the sum using "into".

```
create or replace 
function FGET_EST_INV_SUB (unos_fsub in number, unos_bcycle in number)
return number 
is

amountb number;



BEGIN

select SUM(AMOUNT) 
into amountb
from FMDCUSTINVOICEITEMEST
where FSUBSCRIBER_ID= UNOS_FSUB and BCYCLE = UNOS_BCYCLE;

return nvl(amountb,0);

EXCEPTION 
when OTHERS then 
 raise_application_error(-20001,'An error was encountered - '||SQLCODE||' -ERROR- '||SQLERRM);

end FGET_EST_INV_SUB;
```

Comment: SUM() returns null if no rows were returned for summing. If you return Count(*) as well then you can detect whether no rows were detected. Don't like WHEN OTHERS by the way.

Comment: The code in the answer above will not return 0 if the parameters are invalid, instead it returns a NULL value. I just tested it, many times.

Comment: sorry bout that,my bad.if its returning null then you can just use the nvl on amountb.thanks for correcting.peace.=)